# Знаки препинания в предложении с однородными членами в середине предложения

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Он продавал зелень: укроп, петрушку, лук, которую старательно сам выращивал на своей грядочке около детского дома.

Comment: В каких знаках сомнения?

Answer (score 1):

Правила:

**Тире ставится после перечисления, находящегося в середине предложения, если обобщающее слово стоит после однородных членов предложения.**

`От дома, от деревьев, от голубятни - от всего побежали длинные тени.` (Гончаров)

**Двоеточием и тире выделяется перечисление, находящееся в середине предложения, если этому перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово, а после перечисления предложение продолжается.**

`И много у него добра: мехов, атласа, серебра - и на виду и под замками.` (Пушкин)

Слово `которую` относится к зелени и продолжает мысль. Перед ним нужно поставить тире.

Ответ:

`Он продавал зелень: укроп, петрушку, лук - которую старательно сам выращивал на своей грядочке около детского дома.`

Если не поставить тире после перечисления, то продолжение будет относиться только к последнему однородному слову:

`Он продавал зелень: укроп, лук, петрушку, которую старательно сам выращивал на своей грядочке около детского дома.` || Петрушку сам выращивает, а остальное закупает у кого-то.

Comment: Проблема этого предложения в том, что после однородного ряда стоит определительное придаточное, вот такие примеры нужно искать в литературе. И ваш ответ не представляется мне корректным. 1)  Местоимение в единственном числе ж. рода? Но оно очень далеко расположено от существительного ж.р. зелень, такое сочетание не приветствуется. 2) Тире перед союзным словом которую?  Нет, первое предложение закончилось, далее ставится запятая перед придаточным (или перед любым другим предложением).

Comment: Если не поставить тире, то "которую" будет относится именно к петрушке. Для запятой тогда нужно поменять на "которые". Тире между такими предложениями вполне может использоваться для усиления мысли. Соответственно и интонация будет другая. Например: Вот его новая машина - которую он так обожает.

Comment: Используем форму мн. числа, тогда петрушка будет не в теме. Все правила у Розенталя, примеры желательно брать у него. Или из классической литературы, придумывать что-либо свое  крайне нежелательно. Ваш пример не кажется корректным. Все усиления мысли также делаются по правилам. Пока же мне кажется верным следующее:  однородный ряд может обособляться одним тире  в конце предложения. В простом предложении после него следует точка. В сложном предложении ставится свой знак (обычно запятая).  Двумя тире ряд обособляется в середине простого  неосложненного предложения (без одн./обособл. членов).

Comment: То есть вы бы поставили там запятую, если ничего вообще не менять? Я всегда стараюсь отвечать по факту, не меняя исходный материал, если об этом не просили. Ведь интересует пунктуация конкретно в данном случае (без изменений).

Comment: Ну да,  запятую, но только местоимение нужно использовать в форме мн. числа.

Comment: Ну я бы так тоже сделал. Тогда "которые" относится к перечислению и тире там вообще не нужно. А если не менять число и "которую" будет относится именно к зелени?

Comment: Неоднозначность является стилистической неточностью. Вы же не можете сделать приписку, что местоимение относится к зелени. Придаточное относится к ближайшему существительному, но по смыслу это не так, поэтому это воспринимается как нарушение стиля.

Comment: Да. Но если бы вам попался такой вопрос в тестах. А там ничего нельзя изменить, а только можно выбрать вариант. Так какой знак вы бы выбрали?

Comment: В вопросе просят проверить пунктуацию. Ответ: пунктуация верная, но надо использовать мн. число для местоимения.

Comment: Но при единственном числе лучшим вариантом является тире. Хоть и будет неоднозначность и "нарушение стиля". Думаю, вы согласитесь.

Comment: Может, и лучшим, но все равно некорректным. Да и вариант со мн. числом тоже не идеал. Предложение желательно перестроить, но для этого нужен контекст.

Comment: Мне всегда интереснее исправлять знаки в исходном материале, где есть спорные моменты. Изменить предложение, сделав пунктуацию очевидной, проще всего. Задающих вопрос, скорее всего, интересует именно спорная пунктуация в конкретных примерах. Переделанный вариант хорош как дополнение к ответу. || В данном примере, в принципе, можно решить проблему, если взять перечисление в скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Если после однородных членов следует запятая, то тире не ставится:

Он продавал зелень: укроп, петрушку, лук, которую старательно сам выращивал на своей грядочке около детского дома.

Если после однородных нет запятой, то ставится тире:

Он продавал зелень: укроп, петрушку, лук - и на вырученные деньги покупал хлеб.

Правило из Розенталя:

8. Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире:

Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка, часы, фотографический аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об интересном госте? (Пришв.);

Везде: над головой, под ногами и рядом с тобой — живёт, грохочет, торжествуя свои победы, железо (М. Г.).

Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается. Ср.:

Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.) — запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с;

Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.

Comment: А если человек не знает, какой знак выбрать? Ведь вопрос именно о проверке знаков. || Опровергаю ваш ответ. Вот вам предложение, в котором будет и тире, и запятая: **Он ремонтирует технику: телевизоры, стиральные машины, холодильники, двухкамерные и однокамерные, - в гараже возле своего дома.** У Розенталя есть много похожих примеров.

Answer (score 0):

*Он продавал зелень: **укроп, петрушку, лук,** **которые** сам старательно выращивал на своей грядочке около детского дома.*

Или: *Он продавал зелень — **укроп, петрушку, лук**, **которые** сам старательно выращивал на своей грядочке около детского дома.*

Местоимение ***которые*** используется в форме мн. числа. Согласование по семантическому принципу, а не по формальному. Это связано с тем, что существительное *зелень* и союзное слово *которые* расположены на расстоянии (разделены однородным рядом).